# Commands are not executed when running code through system in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

This is my first time creating a for loop with two variables. I have a bunch of DNA sequencing samples that I want to run through. Each set of data has two files that needs to be run at the same time.

When I just run the system(paste()) in R without the for loop variables, it works just fine. So I know that the issue is with the loop itself. When I run the script below, I don't get an error, it runs but nothing happens.

I obviously messed something up. I just don't know where to go from here.

```
for (j in list.files(pattern = "R1_001.trim.paired.fastq.gz")) {
  for (h in list.files(pattern = "R2_001.trim.paired.fastq.gz")) {
    outname=paste(substr(j, start=1, stop=7), sep= "")
    system(paste("docker run -v /path/:/path/ -w /path/ combinelab/salmon salmon quant -i /path/CanFam3.1_index -l A -1 ",j,"-2 ",h,"-o ",outname, ,sep="")
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: See if the paste output is proper. What happens if you run all the paste outputs on the terminal. Does that work well?

Comment: @Sonny What exactly do you want me to run in the terminal?

Comment: I meant running the Docker command at the shell prompt

Comment: The docker command works. Like I said, when I run just the `system(paste("docker run -v /path/:/path/ -w /path/ combinelab/salmon salmon quant -i /path/CanFam3.1_index -l A -1 D005349_R1_001.trim.paired.fastq.gz -2 D005349_R2_001.trim.paired.fastq.gz -o D005349",sep=""))` it works just fine so the docker command works

Comment: One thing may be the extra space before the `sep` which should give an `argument is missing, with no default` error: `,outname, ,sep="")` should be `,outname,sep="")`

Comment: @desc that didn't work either :/ the for loops runs and ends in less than a second. There is no error so I 'm not sure what is going on

Comment: Does the loop work correctly? If you put `print(c(j, h))` in it, do you see the correct files?

Comment: hm so when I run `print(c(j,h))` I get the following error `Error in print(c(j, h)) : object 'h' not found`

Comment: Are all of these files in your current working directory?

Comment: To re-echo @Sonny's comment, replace `system` with `print` or `cat` and check if these line outputs are runnable in either your terminal shell (Linux/Mac) or PowerShell/CMD (Windows).

Comment: @Parfait This is what I got `print(paste("docker run -v /path/:/path/ -w /path/ combinelab/salmon salmon quant -i /path/can.rna.index -l A -1 D002572_R1_001.fastq.gz -2 D002572_R2_001.fastq.gz -o D002572",sep=""))
[1] "docker run -v /path/:/path/ -w /path/ combinelab/salmon salmon quant -i /path/can.rna.index -l A -1 D002572_R1_001.fastq.gz -2 D002572_R2_001.fastq.gz -o D002572"`

Comment: @desc They files are in the current working directory

Comment: Does that printed `docker` command work if you run in console/terminal? How long does each call take?

Comment: Just to clarify @Parfait last point, when you add replace `print` with `system` in your for loop, not on a single iteration, you get the correct printed statements: `print(paste("docker run -v /path/:/path/ -w /path/ combinelab/salmon salmon quant -i /path/CanFam3.1_index -l A -1 ",j,"-2 ",h,"-o ",outname, ,sep="")`

Comment: @desc @Parfait the output looks like this `> for (j in list.files(pattern = "R1_001.trim.paired.fastq.gz")) {
  +   for (h in list.files(pattern = "R2_001.trim.paired.fastq.gz")) {
    +     outname=paste(substr(j, start=1, stop=7), sep= "")
    +     system(paste0("docker run -v /path/:/path/ -w /path/ combinelab/salmon salmon quant -i /path/can.rna.index -l A -1 ",j,"-2 ",h,"-o ",outname))
    +   }
  + }
> ` The issue is with the for loop. Everything else works without the for loop :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I could see immediately in the code you presented were a few missing spaces which might cause the observed behavior. You can also use `paste0` instead of `paste(...,sep="")`, hopefully the below helps:

```
for (j in list.files(pattern = "R1_001.trim.paired.fastq.gz")) {
  for (h in list.files(pattern = "R2_001.trim.paired.fastq.gz")) {
    outname=substr(j, start=1, stop=7)
    system(paste0("docker run -v /path/:/path/ -w /path/ combinelab/salmon salmon quant -i /path/CanFam3.1_index -l A -1 ",j," -2 ",h," -o ",outname))
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Getting `character(0)` as a result of your `list.files` command outside of the for loop suggests that you aren't matching any files in the `wd` with your pattern.

If you're sure the files are in the correct `wd` or you directly set the `wd` in the `list.files` command (`list.files(path = ".", pattern = NULL)`, you might try a combination of what Sonny and Parfait mentioned in the comments above of running your for loop replacing `system` with `print` and also removing the `pattern` specification in the `list.files` command. This will tell you if you're getting the correct docker strings sent (though there will potentially also be incorrect files printed out that you can later filter by potentially updating the pattern).

Comment: getting the same result as `paste(...,sep="")`  I did get an error running `print(c(j,h)) and got this `Error in print(c(j, h)) : object 'h' not found` so maybe there is an issue with h?

Comment: bad sign, how does `j` look? do you see any issues when you use `list.files` alone?

Comment: This is what I get when I run list.files `function (path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, 
    recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, 
    no.. = FALSE) 
.Internal(list.files(path, pattern, all.files, full.names, recursive, 
    ignore.case, include.dirs, no..))
<bytecode: 0x1096fc188>
<environment: namespace:base>` I also tried running just `j` and got back `NULL` but when I tried just `h` I got back `Error: object 'h' not found`

Comment: try running `list.files(pattern = "R2_001.trim.paired.fastq.gz")` and checking your working directory with `getwd()`

Comment: This is what I get when I run `list.files(pattern = "R2_001.trim.paired.fastq.gz")` 
`character(0)` when I run `getwd()` it brings up the correct working directory `getwd()` I get `/path`

Comment: I figured out the issue, so when I run `print()` I get the following output `[1] "docker run -v /path/r.loop.test/ -w /path/ combinelab/salmon salmon quant -i /path/canine.3.30.19_index -l A -1 D002572_R1_001.fastq.gz-2 D002572_R2_001.fastq.gz-o D002572"` so when I run that in docker the issue is there is no space between `.gz-2`, it should look be `.gz -2` and there is no space after `.gz-o`, it should be `.gz -o` so that is what is causing the issue.. I am not sure how to fix the spaces :/

Comment: I figured it out mane I am such an idiot.. the pattern fucntion was wrong, the name was shorter. I downloaded a subset data. I feel like an idiot. Also to fix the system fucntion above I just had to run `system(paste("docker run -v /path/:/path/ -w /path/ combinelab/salmon salmon quant -i /path/canine.3.30.19_index -l A -1 ",j," -2 ",h," -o ",outname,sep="")`  I just had to add spaces after the `.gz`'s